# Data extraction using Selenium in MS access vba

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, ms-access-2013

I am currently using below mentioned code in MS Access vba and code is extracting main class data but not extraction sub classes data as object required error is visible during execution.My code is given below.

```
Const URL As String = "https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/#/tmview/results?page=1&pageSize=30&criteria=C&basicSearch=Bolígrafo"
Dim myproduct As Selenium.WebElement
Set d = New ChromeDriver
With d
.Start "Chrome"
.Get URL
Sleep 40000
Dim element As Selenium.WebElement
Dim elements As Selenium.WebElements
Set elements = .FindElementsByCss("div[class=rt-tr-group]")
For Each element In elements
trade = element.FindElement(By.className("sc-pZopv gQWHwO")).Text
Next element
MsgBox (trade)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "Sleep 40000" line may not be adequate.
since internet response times can vary widely - such an absolute time mechanism is not a reliable means of assuring that the web content is "fully loaded/retrieved".
You need to look into other means of assuring that the web page is "fully loaded".

Comment: Ok..but i am facing error after complete loading.

Comment: Issue is not with Sleep,actully issue is with following row element.FindElement(By.className("sc-pZopv gQWHwO")).Text